# Left Outer Join With Per Group of Right table?

Tags: sql, group-by, outer-join

I have two tables, `L` and `R`.

I want to have a `Left Outer join` between `L` with each group of rows in `R`.

More clearly, all rows in the left table, must be in result set for each group of right rows.

What is the best query in SQL?

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: My rows in the left table, must be coupled with each group in right rows. My left table is days of a month, and right table is presence of employee. I want to show for each day, whats happen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by `CROSS JOIN` operator.

table L:
[image]

Table R:
[image]

My query:
declare @userid int
set @userid  = null

```
 SELECT T.Id, T.Name,T.UserId,R.Val
        FROM 
            (
            SELECT L.Id, L.Name,R.UserId
            FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM R ) R 
            CROSS JOIN  L
            )T

            LEFT OUTER JOIN R
            ON (T.Id = R.DayId AND T.UserId = R.UserId)
            where @userid is null or T.userid=@userid
```

and the result:
[image]